# Do I use Cursor Hand and Cursor Pointer or both?

Tags: html, css

How do I use cursor hand cross browser?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
<elements>
{
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

[CSS cursor Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp)

Answer (score 7):

Use cursor:pointer only, unless you need to support IE 5/5.5 in which case, include cursor:hand in a conditional comment.

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/cursor.html

Answer (score 2):

Your can use blow css class for all browser supports.
***Note that IE5 and IE5.5 use `cursor: hand` instead of `cursor: pointer`***

```
.cursor-pointer{   
   cursor: pointer;   
   _cursor: hand; /* apply to ie 6 and below */
}
```

You can use [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28417056/how-to-target-only-ie-any-version-within-a-stylesheet) to write your stylesheets for different IE versions.

Answer (score -3):

You can also use your own custom cursor image:

```
.selecty { cursor: url(your_cursor.cur) }
```

This is especially useful for specifying cursors for draggable items. The standard browser cursors are pretty unintuitive for letting the user know a drag is possible.

Comment: `cursor: move` is both intuitive and cross-browser compatible. http://www.quirksmode.org/css/cursor.html