# How can I create CSS rules that are only used by IE 10 and below, without using javascript?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create an ebay listing template but the content in the (CSS and HTML-only) tabs implementation I'm using isn't visible in Internet Explorer 9 or 10. I've tried troubleshooting the issue to no avail by altering the CSS, but since I can't use javascript (because ebay will soon be disabling javascript in listings) and conditional comments don't work for IE 10, I'm not sure the best way to go about creating special CSS styles for IE 9 and 10 only (since IE 11 works fine) which disable the tabs and show all the listing's content at once. Here is a link to a listing using my current implementation:
[listing example](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Better-Homes-And-Gardens-Old-World-Arabic-Wall-Clock-/252520095664)

Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: have you looked into modernizr ?

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Comment: @Leeish Support for conditional comments was dropped as of IE10.

Comment: You should figure out why the content is not visible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to target only IE (any version) within a stylesheet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28417056/how-to-target-only-ie-any-version-within-a-stylesheet)

Comment: @torazaburo Wha? A snippit of code that I've only ever used in my life to fix IE and IE dropped support for it. How ironic.

Comment: But, he only needs the rules in IE10 and below, so, seems ok then. IE10 would treat is as a comment. IE9 & below would use the CSS. Seems like it would work just fine then no?

Comment: I appreciate all the comments but, as I stated in my description, I need the solution to apply styles to IE 10 and below and NOT to 11 or above (@JohanKarlsson the 11 part is why this isn't a duplicate of a previous question). I can't use javascript so no modernizr and I'd love to use conditional comments but IE 10 doesn't support them. I'd love to figure it why the content isn't visible but haven't been able to (may be doctype-correctable but I can't change the doctype since my code is embedded within ebay's) so I'm now trying to find a workaround because this needs to be finished asap.