# IE style issue for select option have both selected and disabled attribute

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have an issue select box on ie only. If it have both the attribute selected and disabled together it breaks the default style. Is it have any solution for this problem?

[image]

<sub>*Click on image for a larger version of the image.*</sub>

Example code is attached with this description.

```
<select>
    <option value="volvo" selected disabled>Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: what do you mean it breaks the default style ? you refferening to the style the option   has in IE ? each browser has different styles for elements such as `select` dropdowns.  a selected  and disabled option has a blue background over it + a grey-ish color. these 2 together end up looking like your picture in IE. it looks different from other browsers because each browser is different. you can't control these things

Comment: usually option which selected have a blue background. but both selected and disabled together breaks the text clarity. You can refer the attached image. or try the above code in ie. It show the difference. Can you please suggest a way to avoid this style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

they only workaround i could think of was to change the `background-color` of the `disabled` option to the default `background-color` a disabled button has, which is `#f4f4f4`

you should also add a conditional so the code will work only for IE . see here for more info > [How to target only IE (any version) within a stylesheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28417056/how-to-target-only-ie-any-version-within-a-stylesheet)

```css
option:disabled {
  background-color:#f4f4f4;
}
```

```html
 <select>
  <option value="volvo" selected disabled>Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: glad i could help. don't forget to rate/accept the answer :D thanks