# How do i change the css to work for both browsers

Tags: css, browser

i have a website with productpages and just found out that it looks really different between chrome and Internet explorer. Example page:
[Website](http://www.zilvertron.com/motoren/)
In IE the images are really large. Now if i change CSS it will also change on chrome where it looks like how i want it.

Thanks for your time,

Sjoerd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set max-width on the image. But use pixels, not percentage!

```
.thumbnail.alignleft > img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 116px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you can set a CSS for IE only

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ieCSS.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Also refer to this link [How to target only IE (any version) within a stylesheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28417056/how-to-target-only-ie-any-version-within-a-stylesheet)

Comment: Will use this in future when making websites because never knew that some of these stylesheets looked different on IE.

Answer (score 0):

I used 
`.thumbnail.alignleft > img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 116px;
}`

Not sure why someone downvoted my question for no reason but for the people that are here on this site to actually help people thanks!

Comment: you don't normally answer your own question. Also, you need to check my answer as the correct one. Thanks