# CSS Grid syntax to support IE10/11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-grid

How can I support Grid Layout for IE10 and/or IE11?

So far I have only found that the `-ms-` prefix should do the trick, but I can only get it to work on Edge browser.

I have tried to look in the Microsoft docs, and MDN network but can't find anything to help.

Below you can find the code I used:

```
@supports (display:grid) {
  .App-body {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 300px auto 300px;
    grid-template-areas: "navbar  navbar  navbar" "leftside content content";
  }

  .leftside {
    grid-area: leftside;
    /*align-content: left;*/
  }

  .rightside {
    grid-area: rightside;
    /*align-content: right;*/
  }

  .content {
    grid-area: content;
    /*align-content: center;*/
  }

  .navbar {
    grid-area: navbar;
  }
}

@supports (display:-ms-grid) {
  .App-body {
    display: -ms-grid;
    -ms-grid-columns: 300px auto 300px;
  }

  .leftside {
    -ms-grid-row: 2;
    -ms-grid-column: 1;
    /*align-content: left;*/
  }

  .rightside {
    -ms-grid-row: 2;
    -ms-grid-column: 3;
    /*align-content: right;*/
  }

  .content {
    -ms-grid-row: 2;
    -ms-grid-column: 2;
  }

  .navbar {
    -ms-grid-row: 1;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 3;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@supports` CSS rule is not supported by Internet Explorer, so you need to remove it to make it work.

Also rules `grid-template-columns: 300px auto 300px;` and `-ms-grid-columns: 300px auto 300px;` are not equivalent for IE/Edge and other browsers supporting grid:

- Replace `auto` with `1fr` if you want column to take all remaining
  space.
- Replace `display: grid` with `display: inline-grid` for grid-container (`display: -ms-grid` for IE\Edge)  if you want column width to be defined by content.

By the way you can remove [`-ms-grid-column: 1`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh772242(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`-ms-grid-row: 1`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh772254(v=vs.85).aspx) for IE/Edge because it's default values for IE/Edge. IE/Edge doesn't have grid item autoplacement and by default IE/Edge stacks all grid items in first cell.

Comment: Thank you, I found this alternative: @media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {}  , thru https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28417056/how-to-target-only-ie-any-version-within-a-stylesheet

Comment: @John-RobertYrjölä Yes, this is an option but you can just omit this CSS rules and media queries because CSS grid layout for IE/Edge won't affect other browsers and vice versa.

Comment: However I tried the 1fr solution to replace auto, but at least in IE11 auto seems to work better. It leaves a min size to fit content.

Comment: @John-RobertYrjölä Yes, in other browsers `auto` is equivalent to `minmax(min-content, max-content)`. And it tries to occupy maximum if possible.