# Google Chrome picking up IE9 specific media queries

Tags: css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, media-queries, internet-explorer-9

I m trying to apply a certain styles to `IE9` browser alone for it to work. I referred a few articles ([Jeff Clayton](https://jeffclayton.wordpress.com/2014/07/14/targeting-internet-explorer-9-with-css/), [ryadel](https://www.ryadel.com/en/css3-media-query-target-only-ie-ie6-ie11-firefox-chrome-safari-edge/)) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28417056/how-to-target-only-ie-any-version-within-a-stylesheet), they suggested me to go with this:

```
@media screen and (min-width:0\0) and (min-resolution: .001dpcm) { 
 .ie9only { /* some  styles */ }
}
```

This seems to work fine in `IE` browsers, but the styles are also picked up `Chrome` browser too. Not sure is that a bug or the intended way. Can someone help me in selecting IE9 alone with media query, thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't reproduce. Can you extend your CSS sample into an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the linked question media queries are *media queries* and not browser queries and therefore *you simply should not even try this*. Because what you are searching for is ***complicated hacks***. They are hard to test and they will make your project hard to maintain.

Beside the fact that I really feel sorry for you that you still have to support IE9 I would recommend one of the following solutions:

**1) Use conditionals**

```
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie-only.css">
<![endif]-->
```

This is probably the best way. Microsoft knows IE is bad and this is why they have introduced them. An important bonus: All other browsers do not have to download shitty IE9 CSS.

**2) Use a class on the HTML-body (with JavaScript)**

```
var browser = {
        isIe: function () {
            return navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE") != -1;
        },
        navigator: navigator.appVersion,
        getVersion: function() {
            var version = 999; // we assume a sane browser
            if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE") != -1)
                // bah, IE again, lets downgrade version number
                version = parseFloat(navigator.appVersion.split("MSIE")[1]);
            return version;
        }
    };

if (browser.isIe() && browser.getVersion() == 9) {
     document.body.className += ' ' + 'ie9';
}
```

In your CSS you simply do:

```
.ie9 #my-elem-to-style {

}
```

The simple rules of CSS specificity will solve your problem then.

**3) Use a library if it is applicable (e.g. Modernizr)**