# Internet Explorer specfic media query or hack for Gmail email

Tags: css, internet-explorer, gmail, media-queries, html-email

I'm working on email and want to toggle section on browser specific. Please check the code below:

```
<!--Showing on Internet explorer-->
<table class="showing-on-ie-gmail">...</table>

<!--Showing on Chrome-->
<table class="showing-on-chrome-gmail">...</table>
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Any help is really appreciate.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to apply specific CSS class based on browser.

You can refer an examples below may help to identify IE and Chrome.

**To identify Internet Explorer 9 and lower** : You could use conditional comments to load an IE-specific style sheet for any version (or combination of versions) that you wanted to specifically target.like below using external style sheet.

```
<!--[if IE]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all-ie-only.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

**To identify Internet Explorer 10 & 11** : Create a media query using -ms-high-contrast, in which you place your IE 10 and 11-specific CSS styles. Because -ms-high-contrast is Microsoft-specific (and only available in IE 10+), it will only be parsed in Internet Explorer 10 and greater.

```
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
     /* IE10+ CSS styles go here */
}
```

**To identify Google Chrome (29+)** :

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) and (min-resolution:.001dpcm) {
    .chrome {
        property: value;
    }
}
```

References:

(1) [How to target only IE (any version) within a stylesheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28417056/how-to-target-only-ie-any-version-within-a-stylesheet)

(2) [CSS3 Media Query to target only Internet Explorer (from IE6 to IE11+), Firefox, Chrome, Safari and/or Edge](https://www.ryadel.com/en/css3-media-query-target-only-ie-ie6-ie11-firefox-chrome-safari-edge/)