# add style position relative for IE and position absolute for other browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, styles

I want to add style position:relative for ie and position:absolute for other browsers

this is my code

```
    <div id="textDiv"  style="display:none; background-color: #434343; padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px; margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 30px; position: absolute;"></div>
```

How to solve it

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring maintenance problematics, the trick to target all browser except IE is to use `@support()` rule which [is not supported at all on IE](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-supports-api).

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to apply specific styles for the IE browser then you should try to use below media query to target the IE browser.

```
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {

}
```

example:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#textDiv
 {    
      position:absolute;
      color:green;
 }
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
 #textDiv
 {    
      position:relative;
      color:red;
 }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="textDiv">This is text...</div>

</body>
</html>
```

You can notice that CSS code inside the media query will only apply for the IE 10 or IE 11 browser.

Reference:

[How to target only IE (any version) within a stylesheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28417056/how-to-target-only-ie-any-version-within-a-stylesheet)

Comment: Please accept the answer. It can help other community members in the future. Thanks for your understanding. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers